# Python remove duplicate values from column but keep only first occurrence

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A'] * 3 + ['B'] * 4 + ['C','B','A'],'col':[2,3,4,2,4,2,1,3,4,4]})

I need to remove duplicate values from both columns but keep only first occurrence.

tried this-

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A'] * 3 + ['B'] * 4 + ['C','B','A'],'col':[2,3,4,2,4,2,1,3,4,4]})
df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```

Expected output:

```
    col1  col
0    A    1
1    B    2
2    C    3
3           4
```

Comment: What is your problem on the code and what is an expected output? It seems that your code works well.

Comment: Do you mean duplicate rows or repeated values in a given column? When you say remove do you mean delete the whole row? As @SangkeunPark said expected output would make this make more sense.

Comment: @SangkeunPark output still has repeated values   
  col1  col
0    A    2
1    A    3
2    A    4
3    B    2
4    B    4
6    B    1
7    C    3

Comment: @user17240949 It would be better to add your problem and the expected output in the question, not as a comment.

Comment: @user17240949 There is no repeated value in your output. The code works well, removing duplicated rows and keep first.

Comment: @SangkeunPark please check edited ques...

Comment: You don't have duplicates in the final dataframe, duplicates are defined by default on the **whole rows**

Comment: @user17240949 Still don't understand. What should the output look like? You have to show what is your expected output. Now, your result looks find with no repeated values

Answer (score 1):

What you want is unclear. You do not have duplicates in your output as a `drop_duplicates` considers (by default) **the whole rows**.

I imagine you might want to drop the duplicates **independently per column**, which in you case would result in NaN values are there are only 3 unique values in "col1", but 4 in "col".

Anyway, if this is what you want, you can use:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted(x.drop_duplicates(), key=pd.isna)))
```

output:

```
  col1  col
0    A    2
1    B    3
2    C    4
3  NaN    1
```

*NB. Be aware, that **any existing link between the columns is now lost**.*

Comment: yes this is the expected output with only one unique entry per column, but with no null values

Comment: The no null values is impossible if you have a different number of unique values. Or you need to sacrifice one value of column "col". Can you explicitly describe what you want?

Comment: what if i drop na values now

Comment: As mentioned, again, please edit your question to provide the expected output.